# Monitor iPhone application API calls

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if there is any way to monitor third party iPhone applications' API calls? For instance if application access address book is there a way to monitor that or intercept call? I understand it may not be possible to do so without jail-breaking, but is even possibility after having jail broken the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes..

1. Download the mitmproxy tool and set it up by going to the folder of
   mitmproxy and running sudo python setup.py install. If all goes well,
   mitmproxy must be available in your $PATH.
2. Start mitmproxy by running
   mitmproxy.
3. Obtain the IP address of your computer by running ifconfig
   en1 (or whatever is the interface that you are using).
4. Set the proxy
   on your iPhone by going to your wireless settings, setting the proxy
   to be “Manual”, and set the IP to be your computer’s IP and the port
   as 8080.

Source and awesome use case...

http://mclov.in/2012/02/08/path-uploads-your-entire-address-book-to-their-servers.html

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

You can howerver, starting in iOS4, see what apps have used location services (you can find this in settings.app).

Answer (score 0):

If you jailbreak the phone, you can replace the frameworks and add any required logging. It's going to be pretty difficult to do, though.

Comment: Thanks! When you say replace the framework(s) (coca-touch etc..) I assume you are referring to frameworks that sit right above the obj-c runtime? If I do replace the frameworks would 3rd party applications still be able to function? Thanks!